# Using dpi instead of pixels in canvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, canvas, pixel, dpi

I have read the "screen support API guide "(http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and much more resources, but I cannot understand how the dpi works.

I'm developing a game, and I'm not using any layouts (I'm going to draw all myself with functions like canvas.drawbitmap). But when I use the Canvas.Drawbitmap function I need to specify the pixels of the screen where I want to draw the image.

So I'm working now with a fixed resolution (1280x800) and I'm using the drawable-nodpi folder and adjusting the canvas later if the screen of the phone is wider or narrow. The problem with that is that the images look horrible when the resolution is not the native one (1280x800).

What can I do to solve this problem? I've read and read during 3 days, but all explanations and examples are related to Layouts, Nine Patches and so.

Comment: have you tried creating a function that be used to convert dpi to pixels? In that way you could handle all the resolutions available.

Comment: search for dp to pixel conversion function or better to have all of your dimensions in resources http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: I tried, but it's still looking blurry when I scale it to dp. Im going to put you an example: I'm testing in a Galaxy tab 2 (10.1, 1280x800 and 160 density) and a Galaxy S (4', 800x480 and 240 density).

Lets say for example I want to load an 600x600 png. In galaxy Tab it's looking perfect (obviously, is the native resolution) but in Galaxy S it looks blurry (because I'm scaling it with a factor of 0.625)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the density of the device being used and multiply that density by some base size that you pick (how big or small do you actually want it to be drawn?)

Example:

```
float objectToDrawHeight = 50; //Specified in plain pixels
float objectToDrawWidth = 50; //Specified in plain pixels

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
objectToDrawHeight *= density;
objectToDrawWidth *= density;

//Draw your object using the new (scaled) height and width
//If you are worried about how the object will look on different aspect ratio devices
//  you can get the screen dimensions and use that ratio as a multiplier
//  just as you did with density

Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
float screenDimensionX = display.getWidth();
float screenDimensionY = display.getHeight();
```

Using density and possibly screen dimensions should allow you to draw anything and keep it scaled correctly. When using canvas, assume everything is in pixels, and that you must do the dpi conversion.

Comment: I tried that, but the density returned by the function in your example (float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;) is 160 (in a Galaxy Tab 2).

Then objectToDrawHeight will be 50*160 = 8000, and then when I scale it to the actual screenDimension it's looking horrible again.

Comment: Hmmm .density should have returned 1.0, while .densityDpi should have returned the 160 you mentioned. Are you sure you are using density and not densityDpi?